# How can I know the current state of signals

Tags: c, signals

Is there a way in C to know the following information about signals:

1. Is certain signal is blocked now?
2. Are we inside a signal handling function chanin (i.e, was the current code called from function which was called as signal handler for certain signal)? If so, can I know what is the current signal?

Thanks

Comment: Glancing at the man pages I'm beginning to wonder if you don't need to keep track yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can know which signals are currently blocked by calling [`sigprocmask`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html) with second argument null and third argument non-null (the first argument is ignored under these conditions, so pass zero).  It'll fill in the `sigset_t` you provide as the third argument.

I'm not aware of any way to know whether there is a signal handler frame on the stack.  I suppose you might be able to use the `_Unwind_*` family of functions somehow but it would be a horrible kludge.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly*, you can **use sigprocmask with an empty set pointer**.

```
int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *set, sigset_t *oldset);
```

a. how can be set to:
`SIG_UNBLOCK` (the signal in set are removed from the current set of blocked signals. It is legal to attempt to unblock signal which is not blocked)

b. `set` can be set to `NULL` (as you don't want to change the blocked signals)

c. If `oldset` is not `NULL`, the previous value of the signal mask is stored in oldset. Ergo, you get the blocked signals in the location whose address is stored in oldset.

*Secondly*, for knowing if you are in a signal handling routine, when you write the signal handler definition, you can **accept int signum as a parameter**, as in:

```
void mySignalHandler(int signum);
```

If you want to know so that you can block some other signals at that point of time, you could just have a blocking function at the start & unblocking function at the end (using `sigprocmask()`). You could even set said signals to `SIG_IGN` status to ignore them while handling the current signal (using `signal()` ).

*Lastly*, **please** read the **man** pages!

**Edit:**
Since the author says he does read them, I recommend using the apropos command to find such hard-to-find functions. For example,

```
$ apropos "blocked signals"
```

gives you around 5 hits, 1 of which is `sigprocmask`

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I usually read the man pages. I know about the signal handler routine, the probably is that I'm not the owner of this function, and this is why I asked this. I wasn't aware of the sigprocmask function. Thanks!